# Enum value is being changed between two contexts

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Can anyone explain what is happening here and how I could avoid this behavior in the future?

#### 1. Here is the code that will be called

```cs
public enum SessionVariables : int{
    Step,
    Volume,
    VAT
}

//Extracted to improve readability.
public static void Save(Object variableIdentifier, ReturnedType value)
{
    //Stuff going here
}
```

#### 2. Here is the calling code

```cs
SessionHelper<int>.Save(SessionVariables.Volume, volume);
```

Both section 1. and 2. are in the same project.

#### 3. The mystery

I had an issue so I looked closer with the debugger from visual studio. Although the `Save()` function is called with `SessionVariables.Volume` the debugger is showing me that `SessionVariables.VAT` is given as parameter.

[image: Screenshot - I halted the program]

[image: Screenshot - One step into later]

When trying to debug this, I realized this issue starts when I add or rename values in the `enum`. It also seems that if I manually initialize the enum's values:

```cs
public enum SessionVariables : int{
    Step = 1,
    Volume = 2,
    VAT = 3
}
```

Then the bug is produced somewhere else.

E.g. The function is called with `SessionVariables.VAT` but `SessionVariables.Volume` is received as parameter.

Comment: You have used any breakpoint conditions?

Comment: Do you have overloads of `Save` ? Why `variableIdentifier` is not of type `SessionVariables` ?

Comment: _> You have used any breakpoint conditions?_

No I didn't. There is simply a normal break point at the line displayed on the first screenshot.

_> Do you have overloads of Save ?_

No.

_>  Why variableIdentifier is not of type SessionVariables ? _

Because I might want to use other object types as variableIdentifier.

Comment: This is surely to do with the type of the variable being object in the Save method. You are passing an enum (value type) and it is being boxed into an object (reference type)

Comment: @jazza1000 why would boxing change the value of a value type? Surely that would be a fundamental flaw in boxing/unboxing as all value types would be guaranteed to change. One thing which doesn't make sense however is that `SessionHelper<T>` is generic, yet you use `Object` as the parameter type rather than that generic type.

Comment: @BloodyKeyboard: Cannot repo this, see Fiddle, working as expected:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/amziHj

Comment: @jazza1000 It doens't make sense to me. Why was it working until I add / rename an enum key? Also changing the parameter type shouldn't change the value that is provided to the function context.

Comment: Try to clean project, remove debug, obj directories.

Comment: @Access Denied I'm not trying to fix this. I'm trying to understand why is this happening and how to prevent this in the future. My program can't behave erratically if I change a value to my enum. Your way to fix the situation is pretty extreme. I could fix this by refactoring _each_ value then refactoring back (e.g. `vat` -> `evat` _[compiling]_ `evat` -> `vat` _[compiling]_)

Comment: @garfbradaz I'm not sure how anyone could reproduce this. Don't forget I'm _supecting_ that my issue started when I refactored/added values in the enum. **More info** : the code is in a ASP Webform project. The enum is in a file the _AppCode_ folder while the calling function is in a UserControl in another folder.
The project is using .NET 4.6 (On fiddle, it's using 4.5)

Comment: Is the enum declared more than once, multiple places?

Comment: Possible race condition? Since your method `Save` is static it could be called from any other place. Check CallStack when you debug your `Save` method.

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen Good question. There are two different enum with the same name but in different namespaces. `Booking.Container.SessionVariables` Vs `Booking.Oil.Booking`. But the second one is empty for now.

Comment: @xneg Good question. If I'm right, each visitor would have its thread. But in our case (in dev env): I'm testing alone. So there should be only one thread.

Comment: @xneg To complete my previous message to you: I also had thought to this possibilty and can confirm this is not the reason:
1. The static function has never be called later.
2. I checked the stacktrace
3. If the call tho `Save(...)` was legit, the type of T would have been `String`, not `int`: I checked and `SessionVariables .VAT` is always associated with `String`

Comment: @BloodyKeyboard didnt understand you last message point 3. Why the type of T would be `String`? Your code calls `Save(...)` for `int`! What do you mean _assoсciated with_?

Comment: @xneg As I understand your hypothesis is: _"There are at least two concurrent threads running at the same time."_ So if you were correct then this means there would be a second thread running the following code: `SessionHelper<int>.Save(SessionVariables.VAT, vat);` since I can tell that <T> in the called function was definitely `int` type (when I halted the execution). However I'm explaining that there is no such line. Lines calling the `Save(...)` function with `SessionVariables.VAT` always define <T> as a `String`

Comment: @BloodyKeyboard that's the point! If T is `String` then it is not call of `SessionHelper<int>.Save(SessionVariables.Volume, volume);` It is call somewhere `SessionHelper<string>.Save(...)` and you didn't show code for this.

Comment: @xneg Exact and I was _confirming_ that <T> is **not** a `string` but an `int` (_definitely `int` type_).

Comment: @BloodyKeyboard ok, understood you. Check out if your `ReturnedType value` is the same that `volume`.